# Unexpected Vertx deploy instance behaviour

Tags: java, vert.x

I don't understand why the callback in this code does not execute after Verticle has been successfully deployed?

```
public class VertxApp{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(new MyVerticle(), res -> {
        System.out.println(res.result());
    });
}
}
```

The MyVerticle class:

```
public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
    System.out.println("MyVerticle started!");
}

@Override
public void stop(Future stopFuture) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("MyVerticle stopped!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never tell `Vert.x` that you are finished with deployment. `Vert.x` calls your `MyVerticle.start(...)` with a `Future<Void> startFuture`. You need to call `startFuture.complete()` after you are done with the initialisation. Same for `MyVerticle.stop(...)`.

```
class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
    System.out.println("MyVerticle started!");
    startFuture.complete();
  }

  @Override
  public void stop(Future stopFuture) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("MyVerticle stopped!");
    stopFuture.complete();
  }
}
```

Or you could overwrite `AbstractVerticle.start()` (without the `Future`) like this:

```
class MyVerticle2 extends AbstractVerticle {
  @Override
  public void start() {
    System.out.println("MyVerticle2 started!");
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("MyVerticle2 stopped!");
  }
}
```